# How do I change target platform in visual studio 2017 c++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I have a project that installs and runs on windows 10 machines but on windows 7 when I try to run it a notification pops up that says there are missing .dll files. I believe visual studio needs to be targeting windows 7 for it to run on windows 7. When I go to the property pages in visual studio, the "Target Platform" field says "Windows 10" and can't be changed. How do I change the target platform?

Comment: Properties->General->Platform Toolset.

Answer (score 1):

The "Target Platform Version" field in the Visual C++ project properties only picks which Windows SDK to build against. For Win32 desktop apps, if you want to build against a 'down-level' version of Windows like Windows 7, you need to set the `_WIN32_WINNT` preprocessor symbol to the appropriate value.

```
#include <WinSDKVer.h>
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0601
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

See [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx) for details.

The Windows 8.1 SDK, the Windows 10 SDK (10240), Windows 10 SDK (10586), Windows 10 SDK (14393), and Windows 10 SDK (15063) can be used to build Windows Win32 desktop apps for Windows Vista SP2, Windows 7 SP1, Windows 8.1, and Windows 10.

> Keep in mind that the VS 2015 / VS 2017 C/C++ Runtime supports Windows 7 Service Pack 1, but *does not* support Windows 7 RTM. Windows 8.0 is not officially support either as users are expected to have upgraded to Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 by this point.

Note that building for Windows XP Service Pack 3 with VS 2017 requires explicit use of the `v141_xp` Platform Toolset because it requires a Windows 7.1A SDK--the last SDK to support targeting Windows XP. See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/11/26/visual-studio-2012-update-1/) for various implications of using this.

Answer (score 0):

The include file  explains it:

*1. Including SDKDDKVer.h defines the highest available Windows platform.
2. If you wish to build your application for a previous Windows platform, include WinSDKVer.h and set the _WIN32_WINNT macro to the platform you wish to support before including SDKDDKVer.h.*

So you need to target the minimal Windows version you wish to support and it will then support any version above (and including) it. That has nothing to do with the Windows 10 SDK which supports all previous Windows versions.